# Unity Button Without an Image?

Tags: unity, ngui, gui

I want to create a button whose clickable area is only specified by a BoxCollider with Unity's new UI (similar to how you would do it from within NGUI). I can't get a Unity Button to work without the presence of an Image component (which ultimately represents the clickable area of the button).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for you.

1) Keep the image component on the button with a sprite, then set the transparency/alpha on the color to 0.

2) Write a separate script that you attach to a gameobject (Or image/button) that implements the Unity event interface: [IPointerClickHandler](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) and inherits from [UIBehaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.UIBehaviour.html). IPointerClickHandler is the interface Buttons use to register a mouse click.

Comment: The IPointerClickHandler is the way to go. Thanks :) The image with 0 alpha eats a draw call :(

Answer (score -1):

If I'm reading this correctly, I think all you need to do is remove the Sprite Renderer component(s) from the GameObject in question. Or -- what if you had a Sprite whose Alpha value was 0? Would that work?

Comment: Currently I'm just using an image component with "None" for the Sprite property.